# Alternate proof needed

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given any perfect square number, what is the remainder when divided by $3, 5, 6$.

I have got from the book of Gareth, a sort of generic approach that concerns with first  taking a number, let $a$ and putting it as $a = dq+r$, where $d$ is the required divisor ($3, 5, 6$). Then, it concerns with the square $a^2 = n$, and factorizing the expansion obtained by using the required $d$ and showing the remainder as one being out of the common factor's product range.

This is fine as the division algorithm guarantees unique values for quotient and remainder for a given value of divisor and dividend.

But, this simple and guaranteed technique gets somewhat long, as shown below; and would request a smaller approach that works without involving risk of being unwieldy for a large divisor.

For $d=3$: Possible values of remainder is $0, 1, 2$.

Let $a = 3q +r$, then $n = a^2 = 9q^2 + 6qr + r^2$. For $r=0$, the value of $n = 3(3q^2 + 2qr)$; while for $r=1$, the value of $n = 3(3q^2+2qr) + 1$; while for $r=2$, the value of $n = 3(3q^2+2qr+1) + 1$.

Hence, the remainder of $3\mid a^2 = 0,1.$

Similarly, for $d=5$: Possible values of remainder is $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Let $a = 5q +r$, then $n = a^2 = 25q^2 + 10qr + r^2$. For $r=0$, the value of $n = 5(5q^2 + 2qr)$; while for $r=1$, the value of $n = 5(5q^2 + 2qr) + 1$; while for $r=2$, the value of $n = 5(5q^2 + 2qr) + 4$; while for $r=3$, the value of $n = 5(5q^2 + 2qr + 1) + 4$; while for $r=4$, the value of $n = 5(5q^2 + 2qr +3) + 1$.

Hence, the remainder of $5\mid a^2 = 0,1,4.$

Similarly, for $d=6$: Possible values of remainder is $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

Let $a = 6q +r$, then $n = a^2 = 36q^2 + 12qr + r^2$. For $r=0$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr)$; while for $r=1$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr) + 1$, while for $r=2$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr) + 4$; while for $r=3$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr + 1) + 3$ ; while for $r=4$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr +2) + 4$; while for $r=5$, the value of $n = 6(6q^2 + 2qr +4) + 1$.

Hence, the remainder of $6\mid a^2 = 0,1,3,4.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your general method, you don't need to worry about writing it out in so much detail. When you expand e.g. $(5q+r)^2$, everything except the $r^2$ term is a multiple of $5$ - it doesn't really matter *what* multiple of $5$ - and so you only need to check the possible values of $r^2$ mod $m$ for $r=0,1,...m-1$ where $m$ is your modulus. And then, since $r^2$ and $(m-r)^2$ will give the same answer mod $m$, you only need to check $0,1,...\frac{m-1}{2}$, since the others will just have the same squares as $1...\frac{m-1}{2}$ in reverse order. For example, with $m=9$, we have $0^4=0$, $1^2=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^2=9\equiv 0$ and $4^2=16\equiv 7$, so the only possible values of a square mod $9$ are $0,1,4,7$.

Comment: If it were possible to get an algebraic expression for showing that the values $m\mid a^2$  have equal values separated at $\dfrac{m-1}{2}$.

Comment: @jiten this is because $(m-r)^2=m(m+2r)+r^2\equiv r^2$ mod $m$.

Comment: Thanks, but there are some smaller issues. In case of odd modulus, need to ignore $0$ for the first value of $m \mid r^2$, as it is not repeated in reverse. But for even modulus, should not ignore the first ($0$) value. Also, the value of middle : $\dfrac{m-1}{2}$ should be replaced by $\lfloor \dfrac{m-1}{2} \rfloor$. In fact for both odd and even modulus cases, need consider only even number of values for the remainders.

Comment: Kindly help in interpreting your explanation, as $(m-r)^2 = m^2 -2mr + r^2 = m(m -2r) + r^2$. How is this equal to $m(m -2r) + r^2$ is not clear to me. I hope, that even with $m(m -2r) + r^2$; it should lead to modulo form of $r^2$ mod $m$. However, I hope it is not possible to prove the reversal of values, at least with this method.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a typo and should be $(m-2r)$ as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simple and acceptable enough to so that if $n = kb + r$ then $n^2 = k^2b^2 + 2krb +r^2$ will have the same remainder of $r^2$ when divided by $b$?

As $0,1^2, 2^2$ have remainder $0,1$ when divided by $3$ then $n^2$ will have either remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $3$.

Likewis $0, 1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2$ have remainder $0,1,4$ when divided by $5$ then $n^2$ will have remainder $0, 1$ or $4$ when divided by $5$.

And $0, 1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2$ have remainder $0,1,4$ or $3$ when divided by $6$.

Isn't that short enough?

We could point out that as the remainder of $n^2$ when divided by $3$ is $0$ or $1$ then then remainder of $n^2$ when divided by $6=2*3$ will be $0$ or $1$ or $0+3$ or $1+3$ but then we'd have to demonstrate $4$ and $3$ are possible.